# Transition Between Column and Line Chart d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create an interactive visualization using d3.j, where the user will be able to transition between a column chart at a point in time and a time-series line chart showing the average of the columns height for each point in time, over time.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this work, and frankly, I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: It's possible. You'll need to .remove() the column chart and then draw the line series time chart.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do this is just make 2 charts, one line, one column.

Then whenever the toggle event is triggered just hide one and show the other and vice versa.

Hope this helps.